# Lebesgue Measure Question - Let $T$ be Lebesgue measurable set:

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A \subset T$ and $B \cap T = \emptyset$. Show that $m^*(A \cup B) = m*(A)+m*(B)$.

My thoughts:  I know that $m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ by having already proven this, so it will be enough to show that $m^*(A \cup B) \geq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$. I know and understand the Caratheodory Condition, and am pretty sure I need to use it, but I'm not sure what test set to consider. I'm working through this myself and would most appreciate a hint rather than a full proof. Thanks!

Comment: Should it be $B\cap A=\emptyset$?

Comment: $A \subset T$ and $B \cap T=\emptyset $ together imply  $A \cap B=\emptyset $